# C2436 '{ctor}': member function or nested class in constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I don't really understand what means the member function in Compiler error

`C2436 '{ctor}': member function or nested class in constructor initializer list`

Using with Visual C++

in my SubNearestNeighbors.hpp to write:

```
template<typename _T>

class SubNearestNeighbors : public ompl::NearestNeighbors<_T>

{

public:

    typedef std::function<double(const _T&, const _T&)> DistanceFunction;

    SubNearestNeighbors(const ob::SpaceInformationPtr &si)
        :
        PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::kdRRTConnect()
    {}

    SubNearestNeighbors()// here is the member function cause the error <----
        :                // but it doesn't have any void in it?             |
        PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::kdRRTConnect()                 |
    {} // error get here, it say member func. or nested class in constructor| 
       // initialize list, while compiling class template member function   | 
       //'SubNearestNeighbors<PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::Motion*> |
       //::SubNearestNeighbors(void) ---------------------------------------
    ~SubNearestNeighbors()
    {

    }

    //...more other function
```

The Code in kdRRTConnect.cpp to write:

```
PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::kdRRTConnect()
:
ompl::base::Planner((const base::SpaceInformationPtr &)*((base::SpaceInformationPtr*)(unsigned char*)0), "kdRRTConnect") {
    typedef std::shared_ptr < ompl::NearestNeighbors<Motion*>> nn_ptr;

    nn_ptr nn_;

    nn_->setDistanceFunction(std::bind(&kdRRTConnect::distanceFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

[Output Tipp tells me that the problem of member function is SubNearestNeighbors(void)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oodDJ.png)

Can some one give me the tipps, what means the member function SubNearestNeighbors(void) in initialize member list, but actually it don't exist any void in the SubNearestNeighbors.

Comment: `_T` is a reserved identifier (due to starting with underscore followed by capital letter), you should not use such things in your code in case they clash with something from the compiler or standard library

Comment: the code in "The Code" deferences a null pointer (even if you fix this compiler error). Also `std::bind` is deprecated.

Comment: Don't use identifiers beginning with an underscore in your own code. They're reserved for the compiler. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: The question can't be answered based on what's posted, but `: PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::kdRRTConnect()` doesn't look right

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @M.M and @Fei Xiang.

Because the _T is defined in the public ompl::nearestneighbors<_T>(Here is the link for that class: ompl.kavrakilab.org/NearestNeighbors_8h_source.html), just analog the other class NearestNeighborsLinear(ompl.kavrakilab.org/NearestNeighborsLinear_8h_source.html), NearestNeighborsGNAT(ompl.kavrakilab.org/NearestNeighborsGNAT_8h_source.html), NearestNeighborsAqrtApprox(ompl.kavrakilab.org/NearestNeighborsSqrtApprox_8h_source.html), which are also inherit ompl::nearestNeighbors<_T>. I write template without other choice.

Here I give the code of Ompl::NearestNeighbors<_T> class, which I inherite and override the function in the class.

```
namespace ompl
 {
     template <typename _T>
     class NearestNeighbors
     {
     public:
         typedef std::function<double(const _T &, const _T &)> DistanceFunction;

         NearestNeighbors() = default;

         virtual ~NearestNeighbors() = default;

         virtual void setDistanceFunction(const DistanceFunction &distFun)
         {
             distFun_ = distFun;
         }

         const DistanceFunction &getDistanceFunction() const
         {
             return distFun_;
         }

         virtual bool reportsSortedResults() const = 0;

         virtual void clear() = 0;

         virtual void add(const _T &data) = 0;

         virtual void add(const std::vector<_T> &data)
         {
             for (const auto &elt : data)
                 add(elt);
         }

         virtual bool remove(const _T &data) = 0;

         virtual _T nearest(const _T &data) const = 0;

         virtual void nearestK(const _T &data, std::size_t k, std::vector<_T> &nbh) const = 0;

         virtual void nearestR(const _T &data, double radius, std::vector<_T> &nbh) const = 0;

         virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;

         virtual void list(std::vector<_T> &data) const = 0;

     protected:
         DistanceFunction distFun_;
     };
 }
```

Here for me is a little hard to give a minimal example. For more detail I complete my SubNearestNeighbors class:

```
template<typename _T>
class SubNearestNeighbors: public ompl::NearestNeighbors<_T>
{
public:

SubNearestNeighbors(const ob::SpaceInformationPtr &si)
:
PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::kdRRTConnect(){}


SubNearestNeighbors()
:
PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::kdRRTConnect(){}

~SubNearestneighbors()
{

}
// All the functions below are just override all of the pure virtual function in ompl::NearestNeighbors<_T>
void clear()
{
motions.clear();
}
void list(std::vector<_T> &data) const
{
        typename PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::Motion;
        data = motions;

}
std::size_t size() const
{
    return motions.size();
}
void add(const _T &data)
{
    typename PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::Motion;

    motions.push_back(data);
}
bool remove(const _T &data)
    {
        typename PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::Motion;

        if (!motions.empty())
            for (int i = motions.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                if (motions[i] == data)
                {
                    motions.erase(motions.begin() + i);
                    return true;
                }
        return false;

}
_T nearest(const _T &data) const
{

    typename PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::Motion;
    // here is about 1000 lines code
    // I am sure here works, because i have test it in main.cpp and that's really 
    // what i want. The logic are just get n random point, which are the around                      
    // small room of state (rstate in RRTConnect )-> build the KD Tree -> give a 
    // searchPoint to find the nearestNeighbor point in KDTree -> convert the
    // nearestNeighbor point in state -> make a new motion *nmotion -> save it i
    //in motion->state

    return motion;
}
protected:

    std::vector<_T> motions;
};
```

Now I give my complete kdRRTConnect, that is fast the same with RRTConnect Planner
RRTConnect.h (http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/RRTConnect_8h_source.html)
RRTConnect.cpp(http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/RRTConnect_8cpp_source.html)

In kdRRTConnect.h

```
namespace ob = ompl::base;
namespace og = ompl::geometric;

namespace PathPlannerOMPLServer
{
    class kdRRTConnect :public ompl::base::Planner
    {
    public:

        //brief constructor 
        kdRRTConnect(const ompl::base::SpaceInformationPtr &si);

        kdRRTConnect();

        virtual ~kdRRTConnect();

        virtual void getPlannerData(ompl::base::PlannerData &data)const;

        virtual ompl::base::PlannerStatus solve(const ompl::base::PlannerTerminationCondition &ptc);

        virtual void clear();

        void setRange(double distance)
        {
            maxDistance_ = distance;
        }

        double getRange() const
        {
            return maxDistance_;
        }

        template<template<typename T> class NN>
        void setNearestNeighbors()
        {
            tStart_.reset(new NN<Motion*>());
            tStart_->setDistanceFunction(std::bind(&kdRRTConnect::distanceFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

            tGoal_.reset(new NN<Motion*>());
            tGoal_->setDistanceFunction(std::bind(&kdRRTConnect::distanceFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
        }

        virtual void setup();

        //define Motion same as RRTConnect, but in public
        class Motion
        {
        public:

            Motion() : root(nullptr), state(nullptr), parent(nullptr)
            {
                parent = nullptr;
                state = nullptr;
            }

            Motion(const ompl::base::SpaceInformationPtr &si) : root(nullptr), state(si->allocState()), parent(nullptr)
            {
            }

            ~Motion()
            {
            }

            const ompl::base::State *root;
            ompl::base::State       *state;
            Motion            *parent;

        };

    protected:

        // a Sub nearest-neighbor datastructure represents a tree of motions
        typedef std::shared_ptr< ompl::NearestNeighbors<Motion*>> TreeData;

        //brief Info. attached to gowing a tree motions(use internally)
        struct TreeGrowingInfo
        {
            ompl::base::State *xstate;
            Motion *xmotion;
            bool start;
        };

        //brief The state of the tree after an attempt to extend it 
        enum GrowState
        {
            /// no progress has been made
            TRAPPED,
            /// progress has been made towards the randomly sampled state
            ADVANCED,
            /// the randomly sampled state was reached, d !> maxDistance
            //double d = si_->distance(nmotion->state, rmotion->state); <- in growTree()
            REACHED
        };

        //brief Free the memory allocated by this planner 
        void freeMemory();

        double distance(const ob::State *p1, const ob::State *p2)
        {
            //define p1's and p2's StateType as SE3StateSpace

            const ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType* state3Dp1 = p1->as<ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType>();

            double x1 = state3Dp1->getX();
            double y1 = state3Dp1->getY();
            double z1 = state3Dp1->getZ();

            const ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType* state3Dp2 = p2->as<ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType>();

            double x2 = state3Dp2->getX();
            double y2 = state3Dp2->getY();
            double z2 = state3Dp2->getZ();

            double dx = x1 - x2;
            double dy = y1 - y2;
            double dz = z1 - z2;

            return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
        }

        double distanceFunction(const Motion *a, const Motion *b) const
        {
            ob::State *stateA = a->state;
            ob::State *stateB = b->state;

            ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType* stateTypeA = stateA->as<ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType>();
            ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType* stateTypeB = stateB->as<ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType>();

            double x1 = stateTypeA->getX();
            double y1 = stateTypeA->getY();
            double z1 = stateTypeA->getZ();

            double x2 = stateTypeB->getX();
            double y2 = stateTypeB->getY();
            double z2 = stateTypeB->getZ();

            double dx = x1 - x2;
            double dy = y1 - y2;
            double dz = z1 - z2;

            return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
        }

        void interpolate(const ob::State *from, const ob::State *to, const double t, ob::State *state) const
        {
            const ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType* s1 = from->as<ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType>();
            const ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType* s2 = to->as<ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType>();
            ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType* lastValid = state->as<ob::SE3StateSpace::StateType>();

            //Separate the path from s1 to s2 into nd Segment. nd = stateSpace_->validSegmentCount(s1, s2); in checkMotion and get the distance difference of X,Y,Z Value form s1 to s2 
            double distanceX = s2->getX() - s1->getX();
            double distanceY = s2->getY() - s1->getY();
            double distanceZ = s2->getZ() - s1->getZ();


            lastValid->setXYZ(s1->getX() + distanceX*t, s1->getY() + distanceY*t, s1->getZ() + distanceZ*t);

        }

        //brief Grow a tree towards a random state
        GrowState growTree(TreeData &tree, TreeGrowingInfo &tgi, Motion *rmotion);

        //brief State sampler
        ompl::base::StateSamplerPtr         sampler_;

        //brief The start tree
        TreeData                      tStart_;

        //brief The goal tree 
        TreeData                      tGoal_;

        //brief The maximum length of a motion to be added to a tree 
        double                        maxDistance_;

        //brief The random number generator
        ompl::RNG                           rng_;

        /** \brief The pair of states in each tree connected during planning.  Used for PlannerData computation */
        std::pair<ompl::base::State*, ompl::base::State*>      connectionPoint_;

    };
}
```

In kdRRTConnect.cpp

```
namespace ob = ompl::base;

PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::kdRRTConnect(const ompl::base::SpaceInformationPtr &si) : ompl::base::Planner(si, "kdRRTConnect")
{
    specs_.recognizedGoal = ompl::base::GOAL_SAMPLEABLE_REGION;
    specs_.directed = true;

    maxDistance_ = 0.0;

    Planner::declareParam<double>("range", this, &kdRRTConnect::setRange, &kdRRTConnect::getRange, "0.:1.:10000.");
    connectionPoint_ = std::make_pair<ompl::base::State*, ompl::base::State*>(nullptr, nullptr);
}

PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::kdRRTConnect()
    :
    ompl::base::Planner((const ompl::base::SpaceInformationPtr &)*((ompl::base::SpaceInformationPtr*)(unsigned char*)0), "kdRRTConnect")
{
    //typedef std::shared_ptr <Motion> motion_ptr;
    typedef std::shared_ptr < ompl::NearestNeighbors<Motion*>> nn_ptr;

    nn_ptr nn_;

    nn_->setDistanceFunction(std::bind(&kdRRTConnect::distanceFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}

PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::~kdRRTConnect()
{
    freeMemory();
}

void PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::setup()
{
    Planner::setup();
    ompl::tools::SelfConfig sc(si_, getName());
    sc.configurePlannerRange(maxDistance_);

    if (!tStart_)
        tStart_.reset(ompl::tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors<Motion*>(this));
    if (!tGoal_)
        tGoal_.reset(ompl::tools::SelfConfig::getDefaultNearestNeighbors<Motion*>(this));

    tStart_->setDistanceFunction(std::bind(&kdRRTConnect::distanceFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    tGoal_->setDistanceFunction(std::bind(&kdRRTConnect::distanceFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}

void PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::freeMemory()
{
    std::vector<Motion*> motions;

    if (tStart_)
    {
        tStart_->list(motions);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < motions.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (motions[i]->state)
                si_->freeState(motions[i]->state);
            delete motions[i];
        }
    }

    if (tGoal_)
    {
        tGoal_->list(motions);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < motions.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (motions[i]->state)
                si_->freeState(motions[i]->state);
            delete motions[i];
        }
    }
}

void PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::clear()
{
    ompl::base::Planner::clear();
    sampler_.reset();
    freeMemory();
    if (tStart_)
        tStart_->clear();
    if (tGoal_)
        tGoal_->clear();
    connectionPoint_ = std::make_pair<ompl::base::State*, ompl::base::State*>(nullptr, nullptr);
}

PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::GrowState PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::growTree(TreeData &tree, TreeGrowingInfo &tgi, Motion *rmotion)
{
    /* find closest state in the tree */
    Motion *nmotion = tree->nearest(rmotion);

    /* assume we can reach the state we go towards */
    bool reach = true;

    /* find state to add */
    ompl::base::State *dstate = rmotion->state;
    double d = distance(nmotion->state, rmotion->state);
    if (d > maxDistance_)
    {
        //si_->getStateSpace()->interpolate(nmotion->state, rmotion->state, maxDistance_ / d, tgi.xstate);
        interpolate(nmotion->state, rmotion->state, maxDistance_ / d, tgi.xstate);
        dstate = tgi.xstate;
        reach = false;
    }
    // if we are in the start tree, we just check the motion like we normally do;
    // if we are in the goal tree, we need to check the motion in reverse, but checkMotion() assumes the first state it receives as argument is valid,
    // so we check that one first
    bool validMotion = tgi.start ? si_->checkMotion(nmotion->state, dstate) : si_->getStateValidityChecker()->isValid(dstate) && si_->checkMotion(dstate, nmotion->state);

    if (validMotion)
    {
        /* create a motion */
        Motion *motion = new Motion(si_);
        si_->copyState(motion->state, dstate);
        motion->parent = nmotion;
        motion->root = nmotion->root;
        tgi.xmotion = motion;

        tree->add(motion);
        if (reach)
            return REACHED;
        else
            return ADVANCED;
    }
    else
        return TRAPPED;
}

ompl::base::PlannerStatus PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::solve(const ompl::base::PlannerTerminationCondition &ptc)
{
    checkValidity();
    ompl::base::GoalSampleableRegion *goal = dynamic_cast<ompl::base::GoalSampleableRegion*>(pdef_->getGoal().get());

    if (!goal)
    {
        OMPL_ERROR("%s: Unknown type of goal", getName().c_str());
        return ompl::base::PlannerStatus::UNRECOGNIZED_GOAL_TYPE;
    }

    while (const ompl::base::State *st = pis_.nextStart())
    {
        Motion *motion = new Motion(si_);
        si_->copyState(motion->state, st);
        motion->root = motion->state;
        tStart_->add(motion);
    }

    if (tStart_->size() == 0)
    {
        OMPL_ERROR("%s: Motion planning start tree could not be initialized!", getName().c_str());
        return ompl::base::PlannerStatus::INVALID_START;
    }

    if (!goal->couldSample())
    {
        OMPL_ERROR("%s: Insufficient states in sampleable goal region", getName().c_str());
        return ompl::base::PlannerStatus::INVALID_GOAL;
    }

    if (!sampler_)
        sampler_ = si_->allocStateSampler();

    OMPL_INFORM("%s: Starting planning with %d states already in datastructure", getName().c_str(), (int)(tStart_->size() + tGoal_->size()));

    TreeGrowingInfo tgi;
    tgi.xstate = si_->allocState();

    Motion   *rmotion = new Motion(si_);
    ompl::base::State *rstate = rmotion->state;
    bool startTree = true;
    bool solved = false;

    while (ptc == false)
    {
        TreeData &tree = startTree ? tStart_ : tGoal_;
        tgi.start = startTree;
        startTree = !startTree;
        TreeData &otherTree = startTree ? tStart_ : tGoal_;

        if (tGoal_->size() == 0 || pis_.getSampledGoalsCount() < tGoal_->size() / 2)
        {
            const ompl::base::State *st = tGoal_->size() == 0 ? pis_.nextGoal(ptc) : pis_.nextGoal();
            if (st)
            {
                Motion *motion = new Motion(si_);
                si_->copyState(motion->state, st);
                motion->root = motion->state;
                tGoal_->add(motion);
            }

            if (tGoal_->size() == 0)
            {
                OMPL_ERROR("%s: Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree", getName().c_str());
                break;
            }
        }

        /* sample random state */
        sampler_->sampleUniform(rstate);

        GrowState gs = growTree(tree, tgi, rmotion);

        if (gs != TRAPPED)
        {
            /* remember which motion was just added */
            Motion *addedMotion = tgi.xmotion;

            /* attempt to connect trees */

            /* if reached, it means we used rstate directly, no need top copy again */
            if (gs != REACHED)
                si_->copyState(rstate, tgi.xstate);

            GrowState gsc = ADVANCED;
            tgi.start = startTree;
            while (gsc == ADVANCED)
                gsc = growTree(otherTree, tgi, rmotion);

            Motion *startMotion = startTree ? tgi.xmotion : addedMotion;
            Motion *goalMotion = startTree ? addedMotion : tgi.xmotion;

            /* if we connected the trees in a valid way (start and goal pair is valid)*/
            if (gsc == REACHED && goal->isStartGoalPairValid(startMotion->root, goalMotion->root))
            {
                // it must be the case that either the start tree or the goal tree has made some progress
                // so one of the parents is not nullptr. We go one step 'back' to avoid having a duplicate state
                // on the solution path
                if (startMotion->parent)
                    startMotion = startMotion->parent;
                else
                    goalMotion = goalMotion->parent;

                connectionPoint_ = std::make_pair(startMotion->state, goalMotion->state);

                /* construct the solution path */
                Motion *solution = startMotion;
                std::vector<Motion*> mpath1;
                while (solution != nullptr)
                {
                    mpath1.push_back(solution);
                    solution = solution->parent;
                }

                solution = goalMotion;
                std::vector<Motion*> mpath2;
                while (solution != nullptr)
                {
                    mpath2.push_back(solution);
                    solution = solution->parent;
                }

                ompl::geometric::PathGeometric *path = new ompl::geometric::PathGeometric(si_);
                path->getStates().reserve(mpath1.size() + mpath2.size());
                for (int i = mpath1.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                    path->append(mpath1[i]->state);
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mpath2.size(); ++i)
                    path->append(mpath2[i]->state);

                pdef_->addSolutionPath(ompl::base::PathPtr(path), false, 0.0, getName());
                solved = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    si_->freeState(tgi.xstate);
    si_->freeState(rstate);
    delete rmotion;

    OMPL_INFORM("%s: Created %u states (%u start + %u goal)", getName().c_str(), tStart_->size() + tGoal_->size(), tStart_->size(), tGoal_->size());

    return solved ? ompl::base::PlannerStatus::EXACT_SOLUTION : ompl::base::PlannerStatus::TIMEOUT;
}

void PathPlannerOMPLServer::kdRRTConnect::getPlannerData(ompl::base::PlannerData &data) const
{
    Planner::getPlannerData(data);

    std::vector<Motion*> motions;
    if (tStart_)
        tStart_->list(motions);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < motions.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (motions[i]->parent == nullptr)
            data.addStartVertex(ompl::base::PlannerDataVertex(motions[i]->state, 1));
        else
        {
            data.addEdge(ompl::base::PlannerDataVertex(motions[i]->parent->state, 1),
                ompl::base::PlannerDataVertex(motions[i]->state, 1));
        }
    }

    motions.clear();
    if (tGoal_)
        tGoal_->list(motions);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < motions.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (motions[i]->parent == nullptr)
            data.addGoalVertex(ompl::base::PlannerDataVertex(motions[i]->state, 2));
        else
        {
            // The edges in the goal tree are reversed to be consistent with start tree
            data.addEdge(ompl::base::PlannerDataVertex(motions[i]->state, 2),
                ompl::base::PlannerDataVertex(motions[i]->parent->state, 2));
        }
    }

    // Add the edge connecting the two trees
    data.addEdge(data.vertexIndex(connectionPoint_.first), data.vertexIndex(connectionPoint_.second));
}
```

Here I clear the Structure of my Program PathPlannerOMPLServer, there are four members:SubNearestNeighbors, kdRRTConnect, which the function nearest(), isValid(), checkMotion(), interpolate() I write by myself. The four functions works perpekt separately, but now I must to let them work with my Planner kdRRTConnect. The Other two Members CollisionCheck and MotionValidator are not relevant in this question. SubsNearestNeighbor inherite the OMPL Source File Ompl::NearestNeighbors<_T> and kdRRTConnect inherite OMPL Source File Ompl::base::Planner. All of the Source File in Visual C++ build a OMPL lib, and My Program PathPlannerOMPLServer use it.Here I draw a picture to simplify what I say before.[Relation between my Program PathPlannerOMPLServer, OMPL Source File and Ompl lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFc50.png)

By The Way I have ask the same question in ompl forum, but the admistrator says this is not a bug, set my question to invalid and doesn't answer anymore.
Here is the Link Issue #436 I have asked:https://bitbucket.org/ompl/ompl/issues/436/about-template-after-inheriting-ompl

Sorry for the example that I can not simplify.

Thanks a lot, I hope some one could give my more Tipps.

eoeo